# Cache profiling with VS2012/VTune

Tags: c++, caching, profiling

I was testing with the following code:

```
const int num = 5000;
int test[num][num];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while(true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
            {
                test[j][i] = 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following Windows counters:

- \Cache\Copy Read Hits %
- \Cache\Copy Read/sec
- \Memory\Page Faults/sec

The results are as following, after a performance session:
http://pastebin.com/L78Pjs9W

Could somebody maybe shed some light on why it still gets Page faults?
Also I have ran the same program with the i and j reversed to try and abuse the cache.
Since I realised that my CPU might detect strided access I also tried random access, still the results of these windows counters don't change much.

I also tried this in VTune Amplifier, giving me similar, odd results.
Random access or flipping i and j gives me less cache misses, using the following:
    test[i][j] = 20;
does **not** give me 0 cachemiss (or close) 
I am using the following counters:

- L2_RQSTS_MISS
- L2_RQSTS_REFERENCES

All 3 methods give me around 7,000,000 references and 3,800,000 misses. on a 25 sec sample.
I expected close to no misses with the [i][j] access, since it has spatial locality and it is predictable.

Am I using the correct counters, any tips?

Comment: Did you disable optimization? It could happen that the optimizer switches the loops to optimize cache access.

Comment: Yeah it was captured in a full debug build (no optimizations)
I also mentioned that I used random access(since without optimization the CPU can detect strided access and cache correctly for me)

Comment: Is the result is same if you initialize the int test[num][num]={1}?

Comment: @dvasanth that doesnt help anything :)

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of 25,000,000 elements, which is 100M.  You haven't stated your L2 cache size, but it is probably on the order of a few Megs, so why would you expect near 0 caches misses?  Your data won't fit in your cache, so you are going to need to swap data in an out (aka have cache misses).

How many loops does your outer while execute for one of your runs?

I'd suggest starting by fixing a number of iterations that runs for about the amount of time you are willing to wait.  That way all your runs are consistent.

It could be that your random probing runs do far fewer iterations because they miss the cache more often.  In fact, given that it seems like you are stopping your benchmark based on time, and the bottleneck for your example is cache misses, you maybe stopping your runs after a similar number of cache misses, and not realizing that the good orders are doing way more iterations.

Comment: Running the same snippet with num = 10 gives me a 100% cache miss (again, assuming L2_RQSTS_REFERENCESis the amount of requests to L2 cache, and  L2_RQSTS_MISS is the amount of misses)

Comment: I also tried moving it to its own function to make sure the measurement is isolated, which gives me 600k references.. 800k misses.. how is that even possible?)

Comment: I changed it to run for 10 seconds regardless, and timings seem to be better - num = 100-150  give me around 10% cache miss, num=200 around 30%, 250+ around 50% misses. my CPU is an Intel i5-4670K.

100-250 would lead to a maximum of 250k, which should fit entirely in L2, right?

On top of that, even if it would not fit, I would assume it would prefetch on time, so when its at the end of the cache, it fills the first bit with the extra data, so it can continue, Is that right?

Comment: 5000x5000 is 25,000,000 ints, which is 100M.  Your Intel i5-4670K has 6M L2 cache, so your data is way bigger than your cache.  Your L2 cache uses 64 byte lines.  A little computation shows that to load 25,000,000 ints, 64 bytes (16 ints) at a time will require 1,562,500 loads per execution of the while loop.  Sounds like you are missing about half of your loads.  Prefetching is not magic, it will help, but it can't make the problems disappear.

Comment: A little advice, don't adjust your benchmarks to make the numbers look better.  Choose your benchmark, run it and deal with the results.  Make the benchmark consistent, so you can benchmark before and after changes and make meaningful comparisons.

In this example, stopping after a certain amount of time has passed is a terrible way to benchmark.  You need to fix the number of loops so that with different access patterns you can compare the same amount of work.  Total time should vary with a different access patterns.  That's the whole point of the benchmarking

Comment: About the data size, I mentioned I tries it now with smaller sizes and posted my results. I did not adjust my benchmarks to make the numbers look better, I am trying to understand t he cache behavior by running different benchmarks (different sizes and trying mm_prefetch etc..)

I stop after 10 seconds, and measure the amount of times the loop ran, which is similar to running the loop a certain amount of  times and measuring the time.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the goal for me is to understand the counters and cache behavior, and so far the test have not made too much sense, for example, 100x100 leads to 250kb, which should fit entirely in the L2 cache, still leads to cache misses, a lot less.. but still.

Also it doesnt have 6MB L2 cache, it has 4x256k associative cache L2. 6MB is the total cache (including L3).